# How to Implement Django Case Insensitive Model Field?

Tags: python, django, model, field

Django do not come with case insensitive model field so how do I make a model field case insensitive without breaking my existing codes? For example: I have a `username` field on my `UserModel` but I noticed that despite making the field unique it would still allow me to use the case variant of the same word:

Example below:

```py
from django.db import models

class UserModel(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)



user1 = UserModel(username='user1') # will go through

user1.save()


user2 = UserModel(username='User1') # will still go through

user2.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a lot of approaches to solve this problem but I will recommend using `django-case-insensitive-field` from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-case-insensitive-field/).

The package has no dependency and it's light.

1. Install from pypi.org

```sh
pip install django-case-insensitive-field
```

2. Create a fields.py file
3. Add a Mixin to the `Field` you want to make case insensitive. Example below:

```py
# fields.py

from django_case_insensitive_field import CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin
from django.db.models import CharField

class LowerCharField(CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin, CharField):
    """[summary]
    Makes django CharField case insensitive \n
    Extends both the `CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin` and  CharField \n
    Then you can import 
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

4. Use the new field everywhere in your model/code

```py
# models.py

from .fields import LowerCharField


class UserModel(models.Model):

    username = LowerCharField(max_length=16, unique=True)

user1 = UserModel(username='user1') # will go through


user2 = UserModel(username='User1') # will not go through
```

That's all!